# How to store a JSON file into a variable using Javascript native

Tags: javascript, json, file, parsing

I've been trying to store the data from a JSON file into a variable in
Javascript and everything were good until the JSON.parse function didn't work.

My file is called test.json and it looks like this:

```
{
  test: 'Hello World!'
}
```

I also tried changing it to:

```
{ test: 'Hello World' }
```

My javascript code is this:

```
var a = OwNet.get( 'core/config/test.json', function( Res ) {

 // Res is the response from an AJAX request (where i requested the test.json file)

  if( Res !== "" && Res !== undefined && Res !== null ) {

    // Here i tried to replace the line breaks, carriage returns and spaces. It failed.
    // (I also tried to remove it)
    Res.replace( /\r\n|\r|\n|\s*/gm, "" );

    // Here i tried to transform Res in an object
    tmp = JSON.stringify( Res );
    return JSON.parse( tmp ); // This returns a string instead an object

  } else return null;

});
```

The only problem is that the variable 'a' isn't an object, instead it is a string, i've been looking for the answer but i haven't could.

Comment: Is JSON.parse( tmp ) returning any error???

Comment: Why are you calling `stringify`? You're trying to de-serialize, aren't you?

Comment: No that isn't. There's no errors. I used stringify because i've read i had to add it before JSON.parse

Comment: Are you trying to replace newline characters within the JSON object, or the actual linebreaks within the object itself? If it's the latter, you don't have to. Calling `JSON.stringify` will remove all line breaks and convert your JSON into a string.

Comment: When I used stringify i wanted to convert Res to string and then use it in JSON.parse

Comment: You can help yourself by reading the JSON docs or a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, change to

```
{
    "test": "HelloWorld!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is wrong, change to

{
  "test": "Hello World!"
}

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much everyone, the answer was easier than i though:

The file test.json:

```
{
  "test": "Hello World!"
}
```

And the code:

```
var a = OwNet.get( 'core/config/test.json', function( Res ) {

// Res is the response from an AJAX request (where i requested the test.json file)

  if( Res !== "" && Res !== undefined && Res !== null ) {

    // Replacing the line breaks, carriage returns and spaces
    Res = Res.replace( /\r\n|\r|\n|\s*/gm, "" );

    // Erased the JSON.stringify and replaced tmp by Res
    return JSON.parse( Res );

  } else return null;

});
```

Comment: You should approve some answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry i have never been in a forum. @AlexanderGorelik and someone whose answer i've seen before. The last one i mencioned gave me the answer to Res = Res.replace ... but i can't find his/her name

Comment: One more question, how can i close this topic??

Comment: In order to close you just need to approve the best answer as you already did.

Answer (score 0):

`{ "test": "Hello World!" }`, the test is a string and needs to be presented like that .